# Accessing the comments from a microsoft vso WorkItem via REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, azure-devops, workitem

So here is where I will get the comments from Visual Studio Team Services, by passing the id of the Work Item from VSO I should be able to pull the comments history from any given Work Item, as I pass 'id' to GetCommentsAsync I get a null result for comments even though the workItem id I am giving the api does indeed have comments.

```
 public WorkItemComments GetPageOfWorkItemComments(string VSTSID)
    {
        int id = Int32.Parse(VSTSID);
        VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(_uri), credentials);
        WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

        WorkItemComments result = workItemTrackingClient.GetCommentsAsync(id).Result;

        Console.WriteLine("Total Revision Count: {0}", result.TotalCount);
        Console.WriteLine("From Revision Count: {0}", result.FromRevisionCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Comments...");

        foreach (var comments in result.Comments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", comments.Text);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It breaks on the foreach when my code begins to look through the result for the comments and throws and error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

From here I begin my call:

```
    public string CreateWorkItem(string title, string description, string 
     PTID, string assigned, string VSTSID)
    {
        Response response;
        VssObject work = new VssObject();
        try
        {
            //work.CreateWIUsingClientLib(title, description, PTID, 
        assigned, VSTSID);
             //work.GetWorkItemById(PTID);
            work.GetPageOfWorkItemComments(VSTSID);
            response = new Response(work);
            return response.BuildJsonResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "{Application:l} - {SourceContext:l}: Error 
            calling 'VssAPI'.", applicationName);
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Testing through postman using a GET:

```
http://localhost:57765/API.svc/CreateWorkItem?title=blash&description=bkkdkd&ptid=BDC19072-9016-4CB8-8741-CDFAF52D0E40&assigned=assigned&vstsid=543
```

Answer (score 0):

Last stable version of REST Web Api libraries contains some known problem with comments: [.NET Client Library - WorkItemTrackingHttpClient GetCommentsAsync does not return the list of comments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/62302/net-client-library-workitemtrackinghttpclient-getc.html)